# добавление числа к переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно добавить к названию число, чтобы переменная с новым названием потом вывелась. Прошу прощения за непонятное объяснение, к примеру:

```
import random

number1 = "01"
number2 = "02"
number3 = "03"
number4 = "04"
number5 = "05"
number6 = "06"
number7 = "07"

random = random.randint(1, 5)
print(number(random))
```

и чтобы после выполнения этого кода вывелось значение ячейки, которая выпала случайно, к примеру `random = 3` и тогда выведет `03`.

Код не правильный, я просто приблизительно так это вижу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import random

number1 = "01"
number2 = "02"
number3 = "03"
number4 = "04"
number5 = "05"
number6 = "06"
number7 = "07"

numbers = [number1, number2, number3, number4, number5, number6, number7,]

#random = random.randint(1, 5)
num = random.randint(1, 5)

#print(number(random))
print(numbers[num])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import shuffle

numbers = [str(x).zfill(2) for x in range(7)]
shuffle(numbers)

print(numbers[0])
```

Что-то такое?

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

print('0'+str(rand:= random.randint(1, 7)))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

еще, как вариант, можно использовать встроенную функцию eval():

```
import random

number1 = "01"
number2 = "02"
number3 = "03"
number4 = "04"
number5 = "05"
number6 = "06"
number7 = "07"

random = random.randint(1, 7)
print(eval(f'number{random}'))
```